# sort strings like "2013/2014" in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to order items by one of their field which contains years written as such : `"2013/2014", "2017/2018", "2014/2015" etc....`

I would like them to be ordered like this : `"2017/2018", "2014/2015", "2013/2014".` This sounds super trivial but I can't figure out how to do it without converting everything to numbers, which I don't really want to do because of the "/".

Any suggestions ? :)

Comment: Isn't it a simple descending order or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: What have you tried? Because doing a simple orderby should work. See [mcve] for guidance on how to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `orderby` as,

```
<yourTag ng-repeat="element in elements | orderby: 'yourField' : true">
.....
</yourTag>
```

You can do this like this on the assumption, that your years are to be arranged in decreasing order. Note the `true` for descending order.

Comment: I had actually made a typo in my code which led me to think that angular had trouble with my string ....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: My issue had nothing to do with orderBy, I just wonrgly named a variable haha